# I need to calculate the likelihood P(D|N) and also to implement my function that it allows arrays as input arguments

Tags: python-2.7

I tried it with this but it gives me an error 'local variable 'l' referenced before assignment'

```
def likelihood(N,n,k):
    """
    Call:
        l = likelihood(N,n,k)
    Input argument:
        N: integer (array)
        n: integer (array)
        k: integer (array)
    Output argument:
        l: float (array)
    Example:
        likelihood(6,10,5)
        =>
        1.190748e-05
    """
    if isinstance(N,list): # N is array
        l = zeros(len(N)) 
        for i, I in enumerate(N):
            l[i]=exp(log_factorial(I)-log_factorial(I-k)-n*log(I))
        else: # N is scalar
            l= exp(log_factorial(N)-log_factorial(N-k)-n*log(N))
    return(l)
```

Where am I wrong? Or is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the function with N not as list, then it will not go into the `if` clause. So `l` is not defined when `return` is reached. The actual error, though, is that the `else` clause is indented. This is probably what you want:

```
from numpy import zeros, exp, log
from scipy.special import gammaln
log_factorial = lambda z:gammaln(z+1)
def likelihood(N,n,k):
    if isinstance(N,list): # N is array
        l = zeros(len(N)) 
        for i, I in enumerate(N):
            l[i]=exp(log_factorial(I)-log_factorial(I-k)-n*log(I))
    else: # N is scalar
        l= exp(log_factorial(N)-log_factorial(N-k)-n*log(N))
    return l
likelihood([6],10,5)
likelihood(6,10,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because [`l` is defined inside the scope of the `if` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules), so when you try and return it the function `likelihood` has no `l` variable defined.

Give `l` a default value, and it should be ok.

```
def likelihood(N,n,k):
    """ documentation trimmed"""
    l = []
    if isinstance(N,list): # N is array
        pass # rest of function here
    return l
```